# Open PHP in same windows passing argument

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to open PHP page with arguments using ajax in the same windows?

I'm doing that on this way:

```js
$.ajax({
  url:'stavkenalog.php',
 method:'POST', 
 data: {'UIDNalog':item_id },
 success:function(data)
 {   
  window.location.assign("stavkenalog.php?UIDNalog=" + item_id);   
 }
});
```

But I want to avoid sending arguments on this way:

```
window.location.assign("stavkenalog.php?UIDNalog=" + item_id);
```

Instead of this above I want to se send

> data

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: why would you run the `ajax` only to have the browser navigate to the page anyway?  Are you saying you just want to navigate to the page and `post` arguments to the server instead of through the `querystring`.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid querystring

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on your intent. It seems that if you're using AJAX, redirecting to the page would not be necessary.

That being said, you could use jQuery to dynamically generate a `<form>` and `<input>` elements and then submit the form.

```js
var data = {
  'UIDNalog': 3
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
  method: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(result) {

    console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('Got AJAX response.');

    var $form = $('<form>', {
      'action': 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      'method': 'post',
      'enctype': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });

    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      jQuery('<input>', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': k,
        'value': v
      }).appendTo($form);
    });

    console.log('Submitting in 3 seconds...');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $form.hide().appendTo('body').submit();
    }, 3000);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```